# Override designer property value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a control that has been used on many forms.

This control has a forecolor property that has had its color set different on many of the forms it is used on.

I want to know if there is an easy way I can set this forecolor property to  the same value on all the forms without going through all the forms individually as there is 200+ forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to do this. The simplest would be to override the property itself:

```
public override Color ForeColor
{
  get { return Color.Aqua; }
  set { }
}
```

You could also hook an event handler on `ForeColorChanged` and change it back, or you could override the `OnForeColor` method.